# Django and Akamai EdgeCache

Tags: django, caching, proxy, akamai

Has anyone used Akamai's EdgeCache in front of a Django-based application? Is there anything specific needed in terms of configuration/middleware on the Django side to ensure Akamai is fully utilized?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found that the cache decorators do work quite well in integrating with Akamai. However, it is important to read the Akamai docs regarding 'Vary' headers.